# not able to get modal data in to angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

I am trying to add user to database using bootstrap modalI am not getting any error but not able to fetch user data.

```
<div class="modal-body">             
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
<label  class="col-sm-3 control-label" >First name</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input type="text" class="form-control"   ng-model="firstname">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Last name</label>
<div class="col-sm-9">
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="lastname" >
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="add()">Add</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

my controller is:

```
$scope.add = function() 
{  
console.log(firstname); //here i want to display fn&ln and make http request to codeigniter api o/p in console is: firstname(not the username entered)
}
```

And i also want to update it in database using codeigniter api call, can anyone plz help me through this?

Comment: try console.log($scope.firstname)

Comment: yes, i get the entered value for the firstname. can u plz help me with next step to add it to database through codeigniter api call?

Comment: try $http https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

You should use $scope.firstname you need to have $scope for accessing scope variables

Don't forget to add ng-app and ng-controller to your template HTML